# NodeJs check in json if array Privilege = user

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, api

my json

```
{
  "webserver_port": 80,
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "privilege": "Administrator",
      "username": "CorePack",
      "password": "$2b$10$xH5rvgSXbdnNsloKZeabFuC4wnhtxbIo4EeuzgdoiN/IOtrsnMmIm"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "privilege": "user",
      "username": "Jova",
      "password": "$2b$10$GQ5EoaQfF.AIzZDgbhDfbunZ1/Gni4pdBDvFqfWswh9rxkMBeWRZ2"
    },
```

And here is my nodejs code

```html
    // Authentication and Authorization Middleware
    // all routes below will only be accessible by logged in users
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        if (req.session && req.session.admin) {
            return next();
        } else {
            // check if a single user exists
            if (state.server_config.users.length === 0) {
                return res.redirect("/createuser");
            }
            return res.redirect("/login");
        }
    });

    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.render("dashboard.njk", {
            config: state.server_config,
        });
    });
```

sorry im still newbie at node and this a public source im testing . so i need to define if user admin show dashboard.njk if not i need him to load another njk file

Comment: What is `state` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the potential code for you:

```js
//The Sample Array You Gave Us
const arraySample =
{
    'webserver_port': 80,
    'users': [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'privilege': 'Administrator',
            'username': 'CorePack',
            'password': '$2b$10$xH5rvgSXbdnNsloKZeabFuC4wnhtxbIo4EeuzgdoiN/IOtrsnMmIm'
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'privilege': 'user',
            'username': 'Jova',
            'password': '$2b$10$GQ5EoaQfF.AIzZDgbhDfbunZ1/Gni4pdBDvFqfWswh9rxkMBeWRZ2'
        },
    ]
}

//Loop through the array
for (let index = 0; index < arraySample.users.length; index++) {

    //Privilege level
    const privilegeLevel = arraySample.users[index].privilege;

    //Username
    const userName = arraySample.users[index].username;

    //Check user's privilege
    //If the privilege is user
    if (privilegeLevel === 'user') {
        console.log(`${userName} has a user level privilege`);

        //Otherwise
    } else {
        console.log(`${userName} has a admin level privilege`);
    }

}
```